# Com upload grande, zend2 não recebe post

Tags: php, zend, zend-framework-2

bom dia.

Tenho uma aplicação que está funcionando em partes.
O problema dela é com upload grande,  com upload pequenos ou sem upload ela está funcionando.
Com upload grande ela não está recebendo o post do form no Controller(?), não estou entendendo oque está acontecendo, alguém tem uma luz e que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Já viu seu phpinfo(), veja esses itens: memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size. Sua resposta estará aí. Sucesso!

Grato

Ríder Cantuária

47 9 9168-8318